# Permutations with variable repetition

Tags: probability

Ok, so I know the standard way of determining permutations of indistinguishable objects, but it assumes you know the quantity of each indistinguishable object.

For instance, you can use it to calculate how many words can be formed by APPLE, knowing that you have one A, two Ps, one L, and one E.

What if, however, you needed a general way to calculate, for example, how many words can be formed in 5 characters (spaces), each of which must be one of A P L E, any one of which could be the character to repeat? For instance you don't know whether it might be APPLE or LAPEL. Also this should be expandable to any number of of spaces and any number of allowable characters.

Comment: There is also the word PAPAL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $c$ distinct characters, then you can form $c^m$ words of length $m$.  So that is the answer if an arbitrary number of repetitions is allowed.

If you have $c$ distinct characters, and you will form words of length $c+1$, with one character occurring twice, and the others once each, we can count this way. The repeating character can be chosen in $\dbinom{c}{1}$ ways. For each way, the positions of the doubled character can be chosen in $\dbinom{c}{2}$ ways, and finally the remaining characters can be arranged in $(c-1)!$ ways, for a total of $\dbinom{c}{1}\dbinom{c}{2}(c-1)!$.